# Por que la función me da este resultado?

Tags: python

```
def test(n):
    if n == 0:
        return

    print("This should print n times")
    test(n - 1)

    print("This should not print")


test(2)
```

Resultado:

```
This should print n times  
This should print n times   
This should not print   
This should not print
```

No se supone que cuando la función se llama a si misma, vuelve al comienzo? No entiendo por que se ejecuta lo que esta debajo de la llamada recursiva.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Por favor mira en la ayuda [ask] , [qué puedo preguntar](/help/on-topic) y [qué no](/help/dont-ask). El sitio tiene como idioma oficial el español, las preguntas en otro idioma se cierran. Te sugiero que la borres y cuando tengas una pregunta clara lo hagas con [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Mati es ya la segunda vez que haces una pregunta en inglés, por favor recuerda que estamos en [es.so] y por lo tanto debes usar el Español o la pregunta será cerrada por estar fuera del alcance del sitio y pertenecer a [so].

Comment: @FJSevilla Listo, disculpa.

Comment: Ahora si... :). Empiezo la votación de reapertura, en cuanto se abra te respondo. La explicación es sencilla pero quedaría mejor con algo de código de ejemplo o un esquema. Espera, seguramente será reabierta ahora que ha sido traducida.

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta es la esperada en recursividad. Voy a intentar explicarlo lo mas prosaico posible a ver como queda :).

Tu sorpresa se debe a que presupones que la funcion se llama si misma literalamente por lo que debería volver al inicio y no ejecutar por tanto lo que hay después de la llamada recursiva.

La recursividad puede pareser compleja pero no difiere en esencia de una llamada
a una función externa desde una función. Seguramente si ejecutas el siguiente código no te sorprenderás del resultado:

```
def maria():
    print('Hola soy Maria. Ya me voy, adios')
  
def laura():
     print('Hola soy Laura, la funcion principal, voy a llamar a mi amiga Maria...')
     maria()
     print('Soy Laura de nuevo, Maria ya se fue, ahora me despido yo. Adios')

laura()
```

Salida:

> >>> Hola soy Laura, la funcion principal, voy a llamar a mi amiga Maria...
>
> >>> Hola soy Maria. Ya me voy, adios
>
> >>> Soy Laura de nuevo, Maria ya se fue, ahora me despido yo. Adios

Simplemente hace lo esperado, `laura` inicia su ejcución con la llamada
`laura()` imprimiendo la primera linea. Después llama a la función `maria`
y se queda esperando a que esta termine su ejecución. `maria` ejecuta su código y cuando termina le da
de nuevo el control a `laura` que termina de ejecutarse.

Pues bien, si en el caso anterior `laura` no llamara a `maria` sino que se llamara a si misma pasaria lo mismo, solo que en este
caso la primera Laura espera a la segunda Laura y luego sigue ella.

En realidad cuando una funcion recursiva se llama a si misma esto no es literalmente así, llama a otra 'instancia' de ella, a una 'copia' y se queda esperando a que esa funcion retorne para continuar ella. Es decir, no es que la función se reinicie, sino que se llama otra vez de nuevo y no terminará hasta que su llamada termine (igual que Laura hace com Maria).

Podemos añadir algunos `print` más a tu ejemplo para ver que está pasando:

```
def test(n):
    print('Hola soy la funcion', n)
    if n == 0:
        print('    n vale 0, yo termino aqui. Adios')
        return
    print('    n vale', n, 'voy a llamar a la funcion', n-1, 'pero me queda algo pendiente...')
    test(n - 1)
    print('Soy la funcion', n, 'completando lo que me falto. Adios')

test(2)
```

Si ejecutamos nos sale esto:

> >>> Hola soy la funcion 2
>
> n vale 2 voy a llamar a la funcion 1 pero me queda algo pendiente...
>
> >>> Hola soy la funcion 1
>
> n vale 1 voy a llamar a la funcion 0 pero me queda algo pendiente...
>
> >>> Hola soy la funcion 0
>
> n vale 0, yo termino aqui. Adios
>
> >>> Soy la funcion 1 completando lo que me falto. Adios
>
> >>> Soy la funcion 2 completando lo que me falto. Adios

Como ves llamamos a la función con el parámetro `n = 2`, como evalua el `if`
como falso continua y llama de nuevo a la funcion pasandole `n = 1` pero se mantiene a la espera de que la llamada termine para terminar ella.
La siguiente llamada `test(1)` hace lo mismo, llamado a `test(0)` y también se mantiene a la espera.
`test(0)` en cambio si evalua la condicion como cierta por lo que llega al `return` lo que hace que termine aquí como cualquier función.

Ahora nos queda `test(1)` y `test(2)` esperando. Como `test(0)` ha terminado `test(1)` que es quien la llamó sigue su ejecución y termina.
Cuando `test(1)` termina `test(2)` puede continuar terminando así su ejecución.

Como ves las funciones termina en el orden inverso al que son llamadas, de forma que la última en retornar es la primera, la que nosotros llamamos manualmente.

Esta es la gracia en realidad de la recursividad y es lo que permite calcular por ejemplo el factorial de un número de esta manera:

```
def factorial( n ):
    if n <1:   # base case
       return 1
    else:
        return (n * factorial( n - 1 ))

print(factorial(10))
```

Si tu idea inicial fuera cierta esto no funcionaria porque el último valor de `n` y por tanto la última función que se llama es 0, y eso retorna 1 (`if n <1`), no 3628800 :). Como ya debes saber, ese número lo retorna la última llamada en terminar su ejecución, que es la primera que se llamó, `factorial(10)`

Answer (score 1):

Por si queda alguna duda, graficamente test(2) hace:

```
# Llamada test(2)
if n == 0:
    return
print("This should print n times")
# llamada a test(n - 1) --> test(1)
    if n == 0:
        return
    print("This should print n times")
    # llamada a test(n - 1) --> test(0)
        if n == 0:
            return # Aca finaliza la recursión
    # Retorno de llamada a test(n - 1) --> test(0)
    print("This should not print")
# Retorno de llamada a test(n - 1) --> test(1)
print("This should not print")
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando la función se llama a si misma vuelve a ejecutarse desde el inicio, tal como dices, pero después continúa la ejecución desde la sentencia que hizo la llamada recursiva.

```
print("This should not print")
```

Se imprimirá siempre que `n != 0.`

PD: este sitio de stackoverflow es para preguntas en español

Answer (score 0):

Es un tema recursivo. Como el método debe culminar su ejecución queda pendiente todo lo que este debajo de la recursión, y la parte que resta se ejecutará en forma de una pila

Answer (score -1):

Vuelve al comienzo pero únicamente no permitiria continuar la ejecución cuando `n` tiene el valor de 0.

Si tuviera valor de 0 se detiene la impresión, al llamar nuevamente la función y obligando a que n sea igual a 0 modificando a `test(n - 2)` o llamando `test(1)`, lograrías lo que deseas:

llamando el método :

`test(1)`

o mediante:

```
def test(n):
    if n == 0:
        return

    print("This should print n times")
    test(n - 2) #MODIFICADO!

    print("This should not print")


test(2)
```

Esto imprimiria únicamente:

```
This should print n times
This should not print
```

Comment: -1 explicación para el  voto negativo?