# Potenciar utilizando sólo multiplicación en Python

Tags: python

He intentado de mil formas de potenciar `x` a la `y` multiplicando (sin utilizar nada de `**` ni similares).

Este es mi intento:

```
def potenciarecursiva(x,y):

  y1 = y
  x1 = x

  while y <= y1:

    multiplicacion = x * x
    y = 1
    x = multiplicacion 
    y = y + 1
    multiplicacion = multiplicacion * x1
    return multiplicacion


d = potenciarecursiva(5,3)

print (d)
```

Lo probé con (5,3) y me funciona, pero prueben con otro, tipo (5,5) y ya no sirve. ¿Me pueden ayudar?

Answer (score 3):

Creo que estas algo confundido, por como nombras a la función parece que quieras implementar tu algoritmo de forma recursiva, no obstante tu código es iterativo.

En ambos casos la idea inicial es multiplicar la base (`x`) por si misma tantas veces como indica el exponente (`y`).

Una aproximación iterativa usa un ciclo (`while`, `for`, etc) donde se repite el cuerpo del bucle. Una aproximación recursiva lo que se repite es la llamada a la función, en este caso 'la propia función se llama a si misma'.

Una aproximación **recursiva** podría ser:

```
def potenciaRecursiva(x, y):
    if y == 0:
        return 1

    elif y >= 1:
        return x * potenciaRecursiva(x, y - 1)

d = potenciaRecursiva(5,5)
print (d)
```

Su homóloga **iterativa** sería:

```
def potenciaIterativa(x, y):
    res = 1
    if y == 0:
        res=1
    else:
        while y >= 1:
            res = res * x
            y = y - 1
    return res

d = potenciaIterativa(5,5)
print(d)
```

En ambos casos se incluye la posibilidad de que el exponente sea 0, en ese caso según las propiedades de las potencias el resultado es 1. Ambas funciones calculan potencias con **exponente entero >= 0**. Existen algoritmos para calcular potencias con exponentes decimales o negativos, pero creo que eso no entra dentro de los objetivos de esta pregunta.

Si tienes dudas sobre la recursividad hace algún tiempo [contesté](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/38252/15089) una pregunta sobre eso por si te sirve de algo. En nuestro caso si hacemos:

```
d = potenciaRecursiva(5, 2)
```

Se produce una primera llamada a la función, como `y` no es 0 pasa al `elif` que si se cumple por lo que llega a ejecutar:

```
x * potenciaRecursiva(5, 1)
```

La propia función llama a otra 'instancia' de si misma y **no retorna nada de momento** porque tiene que esperar a que le llege el resultado de `potenciaRecursiva(5, 1)`. Esta segunda llamada hace lo mismo, queda a la espera de lo que le retorne `potenciaRecursiva(5, 0)` al ejecutar el código del bloque `elif`:

```
x * potenciaRecursiva(5, 0)
```

En este caso si que se cumple la primera condición (`if y == 0`) por lo que esta función no se llama a si misma y retorna 1. Esto es básico ya que actua como **condición de terminación** (al igual que hace `while y >= 1:` en la versión iterativa). Al retornar 1 hace que la llamada anterior pueda finalizar y retornar su resultado, 5*1 = 5. La primera función que llamamos nosotros y que seguía a la espera recibe ahora este resultado y completa su ejecución, 5*5 = 25.

Es decir, la primera función que se llama (la que nosotros llamamos directamente) es la última en retornar (y es la que nos da el resultado) ya que tiene que esperar a que todas las llamadas en cadena que se producen retornen su resultado, curiosamente la última función que se llama es la primera en completar su ejecución y en retornar un resultado.

Tu intento no estaba mal encaminado (aunque es iterativo como digo), el problema es que necesitas una variable resultado (en tu caso sería `multiplicacion` y en mi código es `res`) que esté fuera del ciclo y que pueda ir almacenando el resultado de cada iteración. En tu código en cada iteración del ciclo haces básicamente:

```
multiplicacion = x * x
multiplicacion = multiplicacion * x1
```

Da igual las vueltas que de el `while`, `multiplicacion` siempre vale `x*x*x1`, es decir `x^3`, por eso funciona para 5^3, de hecho siempre retorna la base al cubo sin importar el exponente por lo comentado antes.

Answer (score 0):

creo que puedo ayudarte, una potenciacion recursiva es el hecho de multiplicar el mismo numero, el número de veces que se esta indicando. 
Como regla general la potencia 0 de cualquier numero es 1.

este es un algoritmo de como quedaría.

```
potenciaRecursiva(num,potencia){
   if(potencia=0){
      return 1;
   }else{

     return num*potenciaRecursiva(num,potencia-1);
   } 
}
```

Recurda que en recursión tenemos un caso base (potencia 0 de cualquier numero es 1) y nuestras llamadas recursivas deben ir acercandose a ese caso base.

Answer (score 0):

Este es un algoritmo para calcular potencias.

```
MOD = 1000000007
def potencia(base, exponente):
    result = 1
    while exponente > 0:
        if exponente % 2 == 1:
            result = (result * base) % MOD
        exponente = exponente / 2
        base = (base * base) % MOD
    return result

print (potencia(2,3))
```

Este algoritmo no permite calcular potencias decimales, como por ejemplo

> 2 ^ 2.3
>   resultado 4.924[...]